Is there a relation like $tr(abc) = ( \le) tr(ac) \times \cdots$?
Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive definite matrices. I am interested in knowing whether there exists a relation of the following type
$$tr(abc) = (\le)~ tr(ac) \times \cdots \qquad {\rm or}\qquad |tr(abc)|^2 = (\le)~ tr(ac) \times \cdots $$
where $\cdots$ could be trace of some combination of these matrices.

We can write $\text{tr}(abc) = \text{tr}(bca) = \langle b, ca \rangle$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the Frobenius inner product. Cauchy-Schwarz then gives
$$|\text{tr}(abc)|^2 \le \langle b, b \rangle \langle ca, ca \rangle = \boxed{ \text{tr}(b^2) \text{tr}(acca) = \text{tr}(b^2) \text{tr}(a^2 c^2) }$$
with equality iff $b$ is a non-negative scalar multiple of $ca$ (this requires $a$ and $c$ to commute).
The natural inequality relating $\text{tr}(ac)$ and $\text{tr}(a^2 c^2)$ is $\langle ac, 1 \rangle^2 \le \langle ac, ac \rangle \langle 1, 1 \rangle$, which gives $\text{tr}(ac)^2 \le n \, \text{tr}(a^2 c^2)$, and this goes in the wrong direction to use the above inequality to get a bound in terms of $\text{tr}(ac)$. So overall I don't think it's very natural to try to get a bound in terms of $\text{tr}(ac)$, which I think can potentially be made pretty small although I'm not sure how small.
